# Extend Html.Editor()

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I need to extend `Html.Editor()` so base on some attributes in model to generate HTML. Example:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DisplayFor(Role.Admin)]
    public string Surname { get; set; }
}
```

In this case the generated HTML will not be displayed in `View` if user is different from admin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a sample implementation. Let's assume that you have defined the following attribute:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class DisplayForAttribute : Attribute
{
    public DisplayForAttribute(string role)
    {
        Role = role;
    }
    public string Role { get; private set; }
}
```

Next you could write a custom metadata provider which will use this attribute:

```
public class MyMetadataProvider : DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider
{
    protected override ModelMetadata CreateMetadata(
        IEnumerable<Attribute> attributes,
        Type containerType, 
        Func<object> modelAccessor, 
        Type modelType, 
        string propertyName
    )
    {
        var metadata = base.CreateMetadata(attributes, containerType, modelAccessor, modelType, propertyName);
        var displayFor = attributes.OfType<DisplayForAttribute>().FirstOrDefault();
        if (displayFor != null)
        {
            metadata.AdditionalValues.Add("RequiredRole", displayFor.Role);
        }
        return metadata;
    }
}
```

which will be registered in `Application_Start`:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

    RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

    ModelMetadataProviders.Current = new MyMetadataProvider();
}
```

and the last part is to write a custom editor template for the String type (`~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/String.cshtml`):

```
@{
    var visible = false;
    if (ViewData.ModelMetadata.AdditionalValues.ContainsKey("RequiredRole"))
    {
        var role = (string)ViewData.ModelMetadata.AdditionalValues["RequiredRole"];
        visible = User.IsInRole(role);
    }
}
@if (visible)
{
    @Html.TextBox(
        "", 
        ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue,
        new { @class = "text-box single-line" }
    )
}
```

and lastly to use the attribute:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    [DisplayFor("Admin")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and in the view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
    <input type="submit" value="OK" />
}
```

Obviously this covers only the string editor template but the example could be easily extended to the other [default templates](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-3-default-templates.html) including display templates as well.

Comment: Awesome structure and implementation!

Comment: @Darin, I cannot get this to work.  by placing a breakpoint at the `return metadata` statement everything looks great.  All my additionalvalues and other tweaks to the metadata are there.  However, by the time the View is loaded somehow ViewModel.ModelMetaData does not contain my CustomProvider MetaData?

Comment: @Doug Chamberlain, are you doing this inside an editor template for a property which is decorated with the `DisplayForAttribute` attribute? As in my example, I am overriding the default `String.cshtml` editor template.

Comment: @Darin, that is my problem. I have many classes that implement a common interface that need to have this Attribute display. I don't want to have to create a template for each concrete class.  I'm actually using alot of code that you wrote...

Answer (score 0):

I have the same stuff in my project, but the code is at work.

I wrote an extension method for `ModelMetadata` or / and `PropertyInfo`

```
public static bool IsVisibleForRole( this PropertyInfo property, User c);
```

In my Object.ascx:

```
for ( var field in fields ) {
     if(!field.IsVisibleForRole(this.CurrentUser())) continue;
     //...
}
```

Though, in your case, you might not skip the field, but insert a `<input type="hidden">` instead. But this might be security issue. For details, have look at: http://www.codethinked.com/aspnet-mvc-think-before-you-bind